# What is "allacciamento indipendente" in this context?

Tags: meaning

I'm a translator and I've to translate a contract from Italian to Spanish.

This is the context:

> "Per quanto concerne le utenze di acqua, luce, gas, telefono e quant'altro risulti necessario allo svolgimento dell'attività da parte del conduttore, quest'ultimo provvederà far domanda di *allacciamento indipendente* o, d'intesa con il locatore [...]"

Does anyone know what does it mean?

Thank you!
Maria Sanchez

Comment: For a more complete understanding I think you should add also the following paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a technician, but I believe that *indipendente* refers to the whole *domanda d'allacciamento* (that is, a request that the water, or power, or... company connects the house to its network) and is opposed to *d'intesa con il locatore*. In other words, the tenant may either connect to water etc. independently, on his own, or together with the landlord.

Comment: To the best of my (very limited) understanding an *allacciamento indipendente* is when you have a connection to the water/power/etc. network that is independent of those of the other flats/shops in the same building (probably because when the original building was made, it wasn't predisposed for a centralized system).

Comment: My opinion is that "indipendente" (independent) does not refer to the request, but to the connection itself, so I tend to agree to the previous comment by @DenisNardin .

Comment: It may well be, @DenisNardin and Riccardo, hence my disclaimer that I an nota technician etc. That is what I'd have gathered by reading the text in Italian, but I may be wrong. It would be perfect if someone would find a contract model or a description of the services of some company including this phrase.